# Jquery toggle between two text variables on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a click function where you click on an anchor tag, it changes the background of that clicked anchor tag and the text in another element on the page. Now when you click on another anchor tag, it should change the text to the second text variable.When a-tag clicked a third time(that is the third anchor tag, I have 3 of them), it should change back to the first text variable again. Here is my example, but can't seem to get it working. Also, the background does not change opacity as it should, but I think it is because it is in a td tag-see example

http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/94/

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/tB3pP/3/

I have just used you r code and did minor changes like `var = i` and `i%2`

Behaviour achieved: when you click 1st time its `text1` second time its `text2` third time its `text1` again.

Hope this helps, Please lemme know if I missed anything,

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text1 = "My Text 1";
    var text2 = "My Text 2";
    var i = 1;
    $("a").click(function(event) {

        i++;
        if (i%2 != 0) {
            $("#myTitle").html(text1);
            $(this).css("opacity", "0,5");
        }else {
            $("#myTitle").html(text2);
            $(this).css("opacity", "0,9");
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I'm not sure (it's not clear) if the OP wants to change the title on clicks based on `<a>`'s order, or just any random clicks

Comment: @ZoltanToth Hiya, I concur and completely agree `:)` because we can do it way simple using `toggle` function anyways :) but OP has some nice solutions already with better diversity so s/he will have good options now `:)`

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. I'd like to add one more feature, after the second click(any click), all the values should default back to their starting positions, so basically the function should stop. The reason for this is would like to add another div containing all those elements, and just replace the a tag text values with new ones - It's for a questionnaire, the Title text(text 1 and text2 remains the same through out, but after every second click(no specific order) the text values in the a tags change

Comment: Hiya @DextrousDave Glad it helped you, `:)` you should think of using `.toggle`API like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132090/jquery-reversing-animation-on-second-click hope this helps. `:)`

Comment: thanks Tats, this is very useful. As i said, how do you reset the function and revert back to all the original settings? Basically exit the the function, upon exit, restart all values and start the loop over again?

Answer (score 2):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/96/

```
var title;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            if ( $("#myTitle").text() == "My Title" || $("#myTitle").text() == "My Text 2" ) {
                title = "My Text 1";
            } else {
                title = "My Text 2";
            }

            $("#myTitle").text( title );
            $(this).css("opacity", .5);
        });
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much, like your code.  would like to ask another thing, how do  exit the loop after the second click(doesn't matter which one) and reset everything to starting position(css and all)?