# Reset position after .animate() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to combine the `.toggle()` method with an animation. I've followed the methods laid out in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meD7b/)** as well as in **[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132090/jquery-reversing-animation-on-second-click)**, but the second click isn't returning my div to the original position.

The behavior should be:

1. Click the title
2. Content expands
3. Slide up over the headline
4. Click again
5. Content contracts
6. Slide back down to the original position <-- This isn't happening

**HTML**

```
<div id="headline">
  <h1>This is the headline</h1>          
</div>

<div id="page-wrap"> <!-- contains more than one article, need the whole thing to slide -->
<article class="post">
            <div class="title"><h1>Feedback</h1></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Videos can be more than direct instruction. Currently, how do you give feedback on assignments?</p>
                <p>It takes a lot of time, right?</p>
                <p>Video can be used to give direct feedback to the student because it communicates areas of improvement more effectively than written feedback alone.</p>  
            </div>
   </article>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#headline {
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  width:380px;
}
#page-wrap {
  position:relative;
  top:200px;
}
.post {
  width:300px;
}
.post .title {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.post .content {
  display:none;
}
```

**Script**

```
$(".title").click(function() {
        $title = $(this);
        $content = $title.next();
        $content.toggle(
            function() {
                $("#page-wrap").animate({"margin-top":"200px"}, 'fast')
            },
            function () {
                $("#page-wrap").animate({"margin-top":"-200px"}, 'fast')
            }
        )
    });
```

## [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/Irqpc)

## [Here's a live page](http://dev.brianbennett.org/olc) for more context.

Comment: On the live page you're using jQuery 1.11. `.toggle(function, function)` was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9 [(reference)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). I wouldn't suggest using it

Comment: Oh, duh...I didn't even think to look at update history. Is the best alternative to have multiple events on the same object?